# Конвертировать Netscape cookie в json cookie на python

Tags: python, json, selenium, cookie

Затер до дыр весь гугл русский и английский, но так и не смог найти решения сего вопроса.

Собственно сабж.

У меня есть куки в base64 я их расшифровываю `base64.b64decode().decode('utf-8')` и получаю netscape куки которые мне нужно запихнуть в селениум и дальше с ними там работать. Для селениума нужны json куки соответсвенно, но облазив весь интернет я не нашел ни одного примера как запилить этот конвентер на python.

Все рабочие конвенторы это только сайты. С которых не понять как они там под капотом это делают.

Кто сможет подсказать как это правильно реализовать? Или можно есть какая то библиотечка, но у меня банальным поиском не получилось ее найти.

Answer (score 0):

```
def base64CookieToJsonCookie(base64Cookie):
    encode_cookie = base64.b64decode(base64Cookie).decode('utf-8')
    cookies = []
    for cookie in encode_cookie.split('\n'):
        try:
            coookie = list(cookie.split('\t'))
            json_cookie = {'domain': coookie[0], 'expirationDate': coookie[4], 'hostOnly': coookie[1], 'httpOnly': coookie[3],
                    'name': coookie[5].replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"'), 'path': coookie[2],
                    'value': coookie[6].replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"')}
            cookies.append(json_cookie)
        except:
            pass
    return cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def parse_netscape_cookies(netscape_cookie_str: str) -> list[dict]:
    cookies = []
    lines = netscape_cookie_str.strip().split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('#') and line.strip():
            parts = line.split('\t')
            if len(parts) == 7:
                cookie = {
                    "domain": parts[0],
                    "httpOnly": parts[1].upper() == "TRUE",
                    "path": parts[2],
                    "secure": parts[3].upper() == "TRUE",
                    "expires": float(parts[4]),
                    "name": parts[5],
                    "value": parts[6],
                    "sameSite": "Lax"
                }
                cookies.append(cookie)
    return cookies


netscape_cookie_str = """
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
example.com TRUE    /   TRUE    1740178100  testSameSite    someValue
yandex.ru   TRUE    /   TRUE    1740178100  tag 1
"""
json_cookies = parse_netscape_cookies(netscape_cookie_str)
print(json.dumps(json_cookies, indent=4))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]